# Problem associating a reference to a view in a react native project with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, ref

I have created a react-native project with the typescript template

```
npx react-native init myApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

When I associate a ref to a View in a tsx file I have this error.

*No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly): View', gave the following error.
Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ViewProps, context: any): View', gave the following error.
Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'*

If I change the file extension from .tsx to .js the error dissapears so I suppose this is a typescript problem. Please, anybody knows how to handle this?

These are the versions I'm using and a code example

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Test = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef();

  return (
    <View ref={containerRef}>
      <Text>Hi</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
"typescript": "^3.8.3"
```

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of adding an answer to a comment. If you want to indicate that a question has an accepted answer, you can click the check/tick mark alongside the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this solution is working, maybe is useful for anybody. I have associated a generic with the element type of the reference

````
```const containerRef = useRef<View>(null); ```
````